# OpenNI read_frame() Memory Leak

Tags: python, memory-leaks, openni

Each time stream.read_frame() is called, memory is leaked. Even if I manually gc.collect(), it still leaks. If the code below runs for a few hours, it runs out of memory and crashes with python out of memory exception.

I can't dereference depth_stream in the start function, because then there will be nothing to read from. Is there either another way to handle this through python or a built in way in the OpenNI2 library?

```
from primesense import openni2
from memory_profiler import profile
import gc

def start():
    openni2.initialize()
    dev = openni2.Device.open_any()
    depth_stream = dev.create_depth_stream()
    depth_stream.start()
    while True:
        frame_stuff(depth_stream)
    depth_stream.stop()
    openni2.unload()

@profile   
def frame_stuff(stream):
    frame = stream.read_frame()
    frame_data = frame.get_buffer_as_uint16()
    del frame
    del frame_data
    gc.collect()
    return 0
```

================================================

```
15     46.4 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
16                             def frame_stuff(stream):
17     46.5 MiB      0.1 MiB       frame = stream.read_frame()
18     46.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       frame_data = frame.get_buffer_as_uint16()
19     46.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       del frame
20     46.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       del frame_data
21     46.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       gc.collect()
22     46.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       return 0
```